# do creatures created after a "all creatures get -1/-1 until end of turn" instant get -1/-1 as well?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I cast [Golgari Charm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=265385) (an instant) before my opponent attacks. I choose the "all creatures get -1/-1 until end of turn" and then my opponent attacks with, among other creatures, a [Precinct Captain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270792) which says "whenever Precinct Captain deals combat damage to a player, put a 1/1 white Soldier creature token onto the battlefield".

If the Precinct Captain successfully deals combat do the 1/1 Soldier tokens it creates die instantly because of the Golgari Charm's "-1/-1 until end of turn" or do they survive because they weren't in play at the time the "-1/-1 until end of turn" took effect?

Comment: The answer is "no". How is this question a duplicate of a question with an accepted answer of "yes"? My answer to the other question does answer this question, but the questions are hardly the same if the answer to one is "yes" and the answer to the other is "no".

Comment: The best answer to this question would involve quoting the exact same section of the rules as the other question, and explaining the difference between effects that modify characteristics of objects vs those that don't. I think the key here is that the OP will learn the answer that he is looking for by reading the other question.

Comment: As for the questions having different answers, if one person asks "My opponent claimed that tokens are permanents, was he correct?" and another person asks "My opponent claimed that tokens are not permanents, was he correct?" each question would have the opposite answer, but I think they would surely be considered duplicates.

Comment: @ikegami Would it be appropriate to have a canon question covering both? I know B&CG used to do this then stopped, but it seems very appropriate here.

Comment: @ikegami I think it's a duplicate. The problem is that the accepted answer in the other question is bad, because the OP in the other question makes a general question and puts an example, but the accepted answer only answer the example and not the general question.